# Python regex extract strings between <>

Tags: python, regex

So I have a string like this

```
<TEST>foo bar</TEST>
```

I want to use a regex to extract the foo bar.

I'm using this currently, but it's not working

```
typesRegex = re.compile('<\w+>(\w+)<\w+>')
typesRegex.match(testStr)
```

why?

Comment: If you plan on parsing HTML with regular expressions besides this example, please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) and google why it's a bad idea if you still think you should do it.

Comment: @msvalkon: That's very true, though that post is not the most helpful. I think [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1758162) from the same question is more informative, if not famous.

Comment: @icktoofay there are however plenty of differing answers in that question, which I think make it a good resource. Fixed the link to point to the question and not the answer.

Comment: I wasn't planning on parsing html with regexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `\w` does not match space.

`foo bar` contains a spaces.

Also `</TEST>` contains `/` which neither does not match `\w`.

```
>>> re.match(r'<\w+>([\w\s]+)</\w+>', '<TEST>foo bar</TEST>')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000002AFDBE8>
>>> _.groups()
('foo bar',)
```

Comment: oh so do I need to add a kleene star? (\w+\s+)*?

Comment: how would I match the foo bar?

Comment: ah ok will this work for something like this bladi blah <TEST> foo bar </TEST>?

Comment: @praks5432, Do you mean text with leading, trailing spaces? Then, yes it will.

Comment: @praks5432, BTW do you know difference between `re.search()` and `re.match()`? If you don't, please read [serach() vs match()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match)

Answer (score 0):

This regex is more flexible and conceptually simple: "until the beginning of the next opening angle bracket"

```
>>> import re                     
>>> r = re.compile(r'<test>([^<]*)</test>', re.I)
>>> r.search("<TEST>foo bar </test>").group(1)
'foo bar '
>>> r.search("<TEST>Charles Camille Saint-Saens</test>").group(1)
'Charles Camille Saint-Saens'
```

You should note that `\w` will match to none of `-` `%` `@` etc etc...

- http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

You have already received many comments to discourage you from parsing HTML by yourself.  But I posted this answer of mine in hope that you get the idea of application of finite state machine in parsing texts.  HTH